# bubble scatter plot in plotly is not working with color parameter

Tags: python, plotly

I'm totally new to programming, so it may be very trivial problem with my code.
I'm trying to make scatter bubble plot with plotly, but the size of markers is just random, when I'm using color=... parameter. without it, it works fine. The size column is the same as for x axis, so it is clear if it is correct. See below.

```
fig = px.scatter(data,
    x=x,
    y=y,    
    color='Category',
)
size=df['Cycle life']
fig.update_traces(marker_size=size,marker_sizemode='area',marker_sizeref=2.*max(size)/(30.**2.), marker_sizemin=2)
fig.show()
```

[with 'color'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN60O.png)

[without 'color'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OI4e.png)

Just one more thing I noticed. If I the color values are numerical (I tried integer and float) it works fine, but with strings the size is random.

The data used:

```
#   Column                       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                       --------------  -----  
 0   Name                         20 non-null     object 
 1   Specific Energy (Wh/kg)      20 non-null     float64  <-- x
 2   Cycle life                   20 non-null     int64    <-- y
 3   Category                     20 non-null     object   <-- color
```

Comment: I am not sure if my comments are correct as the data and data types used are unknown. The 'Category' you are setting for color is a string and not a category variable, check with data.info(). And if you don't need the scatterplot size, disable `fig.update_traces()`. This specifies the size of the scatterplot.

Comment: Sorry, should have make it clear what the variables and data are. I added df.info() to original post. And the whole point of this question is that I'm trying to understand why plotly function marker_size is not working if color is categorical type.